# Running compiled code for linux on windows

Tags: go, cross-compiling

So I cross-compiled Go code on Windows(10) for Linux and I was actually able to run the same executable on both Windows and Linux how is that possible?

Comment: you mean you ran the .exe file on linux, and the linux binary on windows, or you're wondering how go can compile X-platform? Because X-platform compilation is not new.... C was designed to be portable, and if you stick to the standard, the same code can be compiled for any system, too

Comment: Things you should look at is how the go runtime works, and what it does. In a nutshell: go compiles big parts of its runtime into each binary. Check the `GOROOT` files, and you'll find OS-specific source files. Some of them will deal with things like goroutines, and memory management. If you can compile the OS-specific quirks into a single binary, and you have a compiler that knows how to spit out executable files in a format that eg windows, linux, and BSD can make sense of, you're perfectly capable of X-compiling user code

Comment: yes I executed the linux binary on windows and the linux binary was crosscompiled on windowsI thought code compiled for linux can't run on windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That'd be the new [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux) (WSL) that can run Linux ELF binaries natively on Windows 10.

Comment: But that shoulden't be enabled by default no?

Comment: As far as I know, it's a developer tool and not enabled by default. You also have to start bash from a Powershell window to start a complete Ubuntu system to execute ELF binaries. It's not something that happens behind the scenes. Let me know if I'm wrong.